# Update multiple rows at once

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which permits me to display all the data in the database as a textarea, I need to update them by clicking a update button!

Based on this one, is supposed to make me edit them, but when i click submit it doesn't...

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <? $id[]=$rows['id']; ?>
        <? echo $rows['id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<? echo $rows['lastname']; ?>">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value="<? echo $rows['email']; ?>">
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
?>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
if($Submit)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
}

if($result1)
{
    header("location:update_multiple.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because you forget your id's

`<? $id[]=$rows['id']; ?>` cannot be passed like that

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value ="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" /><? echo $rows['id']; ?>
```

and script `if($Submit){` should be `if($_POST['Submit'] != ''){`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining `$Submit` in your post, so the stuff in the `{ ... }` is never executed.

You should try something like this for your update:

```
if(isset($_POST[$name]))
{
// update stuff
}
```

In your code, as the if statement never executes, $result is never set, so the user isn't redirected away - it will just show the same page each time.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a post occur when clicking a button should be set as follow:

In the `<form>`tag add the following

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

And lastly, where you check if the button was clicked:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 

//Update fields

}
```

Remember that the submit button name field is case sensitive in php